# Adding a list in Realm DB using insert not working?

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to `insert` a `List` using `insert(List)` but nothing is saving in Realm DB my code is given below, but when I am trying to `insert` one `Object` at a time than objects are getting saved in Realm DB.

```
/* WORKING */
story current = new story();
current.setInc("12456");
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.insert(current);
realm.commitTransaction();

/* NOT WORKING */
List<story> storylist = new ArrayList<>();
story current = new story();
current.setInc("12456");
storylist.add(current)
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.insert(storylist);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Well in the code you **are** inserting `current` instead of `storylist`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce see the edited post.

Comment: There is no reason why this wouldn't work, although I wonder if `story` should have a primary key, and if you should use `insertOrUpdate()`

Comment: Yes it have a primary key.

Comment: Do we only have to use `insertOrUpdate()` when having primary keys ??

Comment: yeah, `insert()` works with no primary key and `insertOrUpdate()` with PK

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Solved my issue `insertOrUpdate()` did the trick (y). You can post this as a answer and i will accept it if you want. Thanks again man.

Answer (score 0):

First convert it to `RealmList`

```
RealmList<TransactionData> _storyList = new RealmList<>();
_storyList.addAll(storyList)
```

Then insert.

Comment: That should not make any difference